What movie has a robotic bees chase scene
My husband and I watched a movie on DVD in 2002 and we remember a single scene, nothing more. Can anyone help us figure out this movie?
What we recall:

The chase scene had an amazing 'flight of the bumblebee' playing.
We think they were robotic bees, but may not have been
It was a B-movie, the type that used to fill bins at Walmart for a dollar or two.
The chase scene had a Rolls-Royce or something similar and may have been on English roads. It had a James Bond feel to the scene.
It was a spy type movie or Kill Bill type movie.
The movie possibly had a dome/green house type lab in it. 
If you could help us out, we would appreciate it!


May be Killer bees - 2002 but I have not watched it

The Avengers fits some of your points:

Robotic bees
A British car (Jaguar IINM)
Uma Thurman for Kill Bill feeling :-)

Here's a video.

Uli, you'd think the OP'd remember the teddy bear meeting, though :D

@Catija, I have to admit I haven't seen the movie. :-=

http://www.hellonearth.com/movies/avengers/bearz01.jpg :D

@Catija, I guess I should fix that gap. :O

Formula 51 (2002) was an English movie with a car chase and rolls roycy type vehicle
Die Another Day (2002) James bond car escape from an domed ice palace
Agent Cody Banks 1 & 2 (2003-4) featured car chases, rolls royces, cheesy spy themes, and symphonic-style scoring

I think the movie "The Avengers" could be correct. This could be the scene you mentioned
http://www.joblo.com/videos/movie-clips/the-avengers-bees
